# Controller and input form html use var Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I use the angularjs framework, I created an form.html and a controller.js with a variable that retrieves the SSID of a box.
How to automatically assign the value of the variable in the form.
This is an input field.
When launching the application, the form should display the SSID automatically without the user needing to do so.

Thank you kindly help me.

```js
'use strict';

angular.module('djoro.controllers')
  .controller('WifiSmartConfigCtrl', function ($scope, $window, $ionicPlatform) {
    $scope.getSSID = function () {
      var onSuccess = function (SSID) {
        document.write(SSID);
      };
      
      var onFail = function () {
        
      };

      $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
        $window.cordova.plugins.Smartconfig.getSSID(onSuccess, onFail);
      });
    };
  });
```

```html
<ion-pane>
  <ion-content ng-controller="WifiSmartConfigCtrl">
    <form novalidate class="simple-form">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>WI-FI</legend>
        <div class="list input-fields">
          <label class="item item-input">
            <span class="input-label">SSID :</span>
            <input type="text" name="test" value="getSSID()" required show-hide-input>
          </label>
          <label class="item item-input" show-hide-container>
            <span class="input-label">Password :</span>
            <input type="text" name="password" required show-hide-input>
          </label>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </ion-content>
</ion-pane>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an ng-model to the input field like so:

```
<label class="item item-input">
   <span class="input-label">SSID :</span>
   <input type="text" name="test" ng-model="SSID" required show-hide-input>
</label>
```

then in your controller assign the value of SSID on the $scope:

```
$scope.SSID = [some_value]
```

see this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/3G71A8TFAGIUuCOm9nuF?p=preview)

As you can see I have assigned the value of SSID manually, you can add it dynamically by assigning it in the callback of your function like so:

```
$scope.SSID = {}
var onSuccess = function (SSID) {
  document.write(SSID);
  $scope.SSID = SSID
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I tried to use callback in the function but it 's still not working .
Could you give me an example of a callback to automatically assign my SSID.
thank you a lot

Comment: How do you get the value of SSID?

Comment: I use a plugin cordova - natif java

The method works . I can see the SSID in a window with an alert in the controller ng ​​-click on the form. But it does not work when I use ng -model . I want the SSID displayed without opening a window alert .

Comment: JAVA PLUGINS

https://www.dropbox.com/s/p5c9bltwp3wszq5/java.jpg?dl=0 


Screenshot SSID BY ALERT DONE
https://www.dropbox.com/s/z99px85y5y92lbw/Screenshot_2015-09-18-17-25-02.jpg?dl=0

Comment: can you post your SSID so I can see how to access the value

Comment: Here the 4 files used to pay Create the plug-in wi-fi Cordova.

http://plnkr.co/edit/2WuDdxZnXWHkXW1oYJkT?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

use the `ng-model` directive, it's exactly it's purpose :

```
'use strict';

angular.module('djoro.controllers')

.controller('WifiSmartConfigCtrl', function($scope, $window, $ionicPlatform) {
  $scope.SSID = {};
  $scope.getSSID = function() {
      var onSuccess = function(SSID) {
          $scope.SSID = SSID;
      };
      var onFail = function() {};

      $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
          $window.cordova.plugins.Smartconfig.getSSID(onSuccess, onFail);
      });
  };
});
```

and in your view :

```
<input type="text" name="test" ng-model="SSID" required show-hide-input>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
it does not work.
The input field returns [object Object ] .
An idea ?

Thank you

Comment: If you have [object Object] it means that's a complete object and not a string that is returned by the getSSID function. You just have to find the attribute containing the SSID name (SSID.name maybe ?) to display it

Comment: Here the 4 files used to pay Create the plug-in wi-fi Cordova. 

http://plnkr.co/edit/2WuDdxZnXWHkXW1oYJkT?p=preview